# How to remove line breaks in string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
    text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
    console.log("Command: " + text + "textthatshouldbeinthesameline");
    if (text == 'quit') {
        console.log("Quitting");
        done();
    }
});

function done() {
  console.log('Now that process.stdin is paused, there is nothing more to do.');
  process.exit();
}
```

And this is what happens:

[image]

It seems like there are some line breaks, I tried to replace them, but as you see: without effect.

When I type "quit" it also isn't recognized by if statement.

Answer (score 6):

`replace` doesn't change the string, as strings are immutable. It returns a new string.

Change

```
text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
```

to

```
text = text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
```

Comment: Indeed O.o Stupid mistake, I though it was something more complicated :P